# changing the list and detail view templates ng-view

Tags: angularjs

I want to load a template in main page, list and detail view for example, can i do it with `stateprovider` or i have to use `routeprovider`? How can i import template there not changing the link?

```
app.config(function config( $stateProvider ) {
  $stateProvider.state('inventory',{
    url:'/inventory',
        views: {
            "main": {
                controller: 'InventoryCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'inventory/main.tpl.html'
            }
        },
        data:{ pageTitle: 'Inventory' }
  }
  ).state('add',{
    url:'/inventory/list',
        views: {
            "main": {
                controller: 'InventoryCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'inventory/add.tpl.html'
            }
        },
        data:{ pageTitle: 'List field' }
  });
});
```

Template

```
<li data-ng-class="{active: listViewEnabled}" class="toolbaritem"><a href="#/inventory/list"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span> List View</a></li>

 <div ng-view="main"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case useful directive `ng-include`.

e.g. `<div ng-include="template.url"></div>`

and in controller:

```
$scope.changeTemplate = function(templateName){
    $scope.template.url = '/path/to/'+templateName;
}
```

docs: http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/docs/api/ng.directive:ngInclude